# Expand tuple into dataframe using Scala Spark

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark

i have a tuple of 2 elements like this :

`Tuple2(“String1, String2”, ArrayList(“String3”, “String4”))` 
=> 1st element is a string with comma separated string values 
=> 2nd element is an arraylist that contains a list of string

i would like to have a data frame like this :

```
Col1        Col2        Col3
1           String1     String3
2           String1     String4
3           String2     String3
4           String2     String4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TL;DR

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, explode, monotonically_increasing_id, split}

df
    // `split` "String1, String2" into separate values, then create a row per value using `explode`
    .withColumn("Col2", explode(split(col("_1"), ", ")))
    // create a row per value in the list: "String3", "String4"
    .withColumn("Col3", explode(col("_2")))
    // now that we have our 4 rows, add a new column with an incrementing number
    .withColumn("Col1", monotonically_increasing_id() + 1)
    // only keep the columns we care about
    .select("Col1", "Col2", "Col3")
    .show(false)
```

---

## Full Answer

Starting with your example:

```scala
val tuple2 = Tuple2("String1, String2", List("String3", "String4"))
```

and turning it into a DataFrame:

```scala
val df = List(tuple2).toDF("_1", "_2")

df.show(false)
```

which gives:

```
+----------------+------------------+
|_1              |_2                |
+----------------+------------------+
|String1, String2|[String3, String4]|
+----------------+------------------+
```

Now we are ready for the transformation:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, explode, monotonically_increasing_id, split}

df
    // `split` "String1, String2" into separate values, then create a row per value using `explode`
    .withColumn("Col2", explode(split(col("_1"), ", ")))
    // create a row per value in the list: "String3", "String4"
    .withColumn("Col3", explode(col("_2")))
    // now that we have our 4 rows, add a new column with an incrementing number
    .withColumn("Col1", monotonically_increasing_id() + 1)
    // only keep the columns we care about
    .select("Col1", "Col2", "Col3")
    .show(false)
```

which gives:

```
+----+-------+-------+
|Col1|Col2   |Col3   |
+----+-------+-------+
|1   |String1|String3|
|2   |String1|String4|
|3   |String2|String3|
|4   |String2|String4|
+----+-------+-------+
```

---

## Extra reading for further detail

It is worth noting that the order of the operations is key:

1. First we [explode](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.scala#L4270) `"String1"` and `"String2"` into their own rows:

```scala
df
    .withColumn("Col2", explode(split(col("_1"), ", ")))
    .select("Col2")
    .show(false)
```

gives:

```
+-------+
|Col2   |
+-------+
|String1|
|String2|
+-------+
```

where we go from 1 original row, to two.

2. then we explode `"String3", "String4"`:

```scala
df
    .withColumn("Col2", explode(split(col("_1"), ", ")))
    .withColumn("Col3", explode(col("_2")))
    .select("Col2", "Col3")
    .show(false)
```

gives:

```
+-------+-------+
|Col2   |Col3   |
+-------+-------+
|String1|String3|
|String1|String4|
|String2|String3|
|String2|String4|
+-------+-------+
```

3. finally we add the incrementing count. If we did this earlier we copy the same number value to multiple rows.

for example:

```scala
df
    // here we add `Col1` to a Dataset of only one row! So we only have the value `1`
    .withColumn("Col1", monotonically_increasing_id() + 1)
    // here we explode row 1, copying the value of `Col1`
    .withColumn("Col2", explode(split(col("_1"), ", ")))
    .withColumn("Col3", explode(col("_2")))
    .select("Col1", "Col2", "Col3")
    .show(false)
```

gives:

```
+----+-------+-------+
|Col1|Col2   |Col3   |
+----+-------+-------+
|1   |String1|String3|
|1   |String1|String4|
|1   |String2|String3|
|1   |String2|String4|
+----+-------+-------+
```